# How do I change the source of my ethernet connection

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, ethernet

My router has 2 SSIDs. One for a 2.4GHz connection and one for a 5GHz connection like most internet connections have nowadays. I use ethernet to connect to the internet from my computer. I have a 100mbps internet plan. However, I only get about 45. I believe it's because it's using the 2.4GHz channel. How do I set it to the 5GHz?

If it's not using the 2.4GHz channel, what could be the issue. Because on [fast](https://fast.com) it shows 95-98mbps while on [speedtest](https://speetest.net) it shows only about 45-50mbps.

Edit:

I wanted to let you know that when downloading a game from Steam, I am getting the full speed, however, when downloading from Epic Games or any other launcher, I'm getting half the speed

Comment: Are the SSID for the 2.4GHz and the 5GHz the same name like "MYROUTER", or are they name differently like "MYROUTER" and "MYROUTER5"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIDs and the "2.4 GHz" / "5 GHz" bands have nothing to do with your internet connection.

They only affect the actual Wi-Fi radio link between computer and router. But when you're using a wired Ethernet connection, then you're not using Wi-Fi, meaning the choice of radio band is irrelevant and the SSIDs don't come into play either.

Either way, if your connection (whether to router or to ISP) were the problem, then it would generally affect *all* downloads equally – e.g. if you *were* on 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi and were physically limited to ~50 Mbps due to the narrow channel, then there's no way some programs could bypass that but others couldn't.

It's somewhat more likely that *your ISP* has direct physical connections to the Netflix (Fast.com) and Steam CDNs, but doesn't have the same for other services, meaning that downloads from Epic &c. must go through the ISP's regular Internet uplinks which might be running at their full capacity already.

*(Not all CDNs offer direct connections at all, or under acceptable terms, or in suitable physical locations, or it might just not be worth the effort for the ISP...)*

The same goes for Speedtest.net – if the selected server isn't run *by* your ISP, then you're not actually testing your own connection only, you're testing the "slowest link" between you and the server.

Comment: Oh alright. Thanks a lot for your answer.